# Post a javascript object with prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

Requirements:

- I would create an javascript object with methods and properties.
- I would post this object.

My code:

```
        var SessionManager = (function (my) {
            function addUrl(urlHistory) {
                if (!urlHistory) throw new TypeError('"urlHistory" is null or not defined');
                if (!(urlHistory instanceof UrlHistory)) throw new TypeError('"urlHistory" is not an "UrlHistory" object');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/CollateralManagement/Session/AddUrl',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(), model: urlHistory }
                });
            }

        my.addUrl = addUrl;

        return my;
        })(SessionManager || {});

        var UrlHistory = function (area, controller, view, params) {
            if (params && !Array.isArray(params)) throw new TypeError('The variable "params" is not null and not an array');

            var me = this;

            me.Area = area;
            me.Controller = controller;
            me.View = view;
            me.Params = Array.isArray(params) ? params : [];
        };

        UrlHistory.prototype.coucou = function () {
            console.log(this);
        };

        UrlHistory.prototype.AddParam = function (key, value) {
            this.Params.push({ "Key": key, "Value": value });

            return this;
        };

        //I run the code with this exemple:
        var uh = new UrlHistory("toto", "tata", "titi");
        uh.AddParam("z", "z").AddParam("a", "a");
        SessionManager.addUrl(uh);
```

My object look great:
UrlHistory {Area: "toto", Controller: "tata", View: "titi", Params: Array[2]}

But when I enter in the ajax method I have this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

I have tried the same call ajax without to add prototypes, and All is OK.

When the ajax function is run, my 2 methods are called but "this" is "Window" and not "UrlHistory".

Questions:

- Why methods are called when the post is made?
- How to post my object?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use "class" when creating the SessionManager Prototype? Otherwise addUrl is attached to the window object. Please show more code.

Comment: It seems like `this.Params` is undefined. Perhaps the `this` is not what you expect? Try debugging your code a bit!

Comment: TJHeuvel , please read me until the end.

When I use my method here: "uh.AddParam("z", "z").AddParam("a", "a");"

The "this" is "UrlHistory" (this is normal)

But when the call ajax is run, my method is again called and the "this" is "Window" and parameters is "undefined", why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will call the function `something`

```
var Test = function(){
  this.name="Hello World";
}
Test.prototype.something = function(){
  console.log(".... something has been called",this);
  throw new Error("what is the stack?");
}

jQuery.post("",Object.create(new Test()))
```

That is because the [following line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L61) in the jQuery code checks if your object member is a function, if so it will call that function and use the result value.

jQuery uses `jQuery.param` to serialize the object to http post or get parameters so `jQuery.param(new Test())` would throw the same error.

You would like to prevent jQuery from calling the function but I could not find anything in the documentation to override the serialize function but you could add a funciton to your urlHistory type to convert to data:

```
var urlHistory = function(){
  this.name="Hello World";
}
urlHistory.prototype.something = function(){
  console.log(".... something has been called",this);
  throw new Error("what is the stack?");
};
urlHistory.prototype.toData =  function(){
    var ret = {};
    //this works in your example but if nested objects have functions
    //  it may still fail
    for ( prefix in this ) {
        if(typeof this[ prefix ] !== "function" ){
          ret[ prefix ] = this[ prefix ];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log("..... working:",jQuery.param((new urlHistory()).toData()))
```

In your case you can add `toData` to urlHistory and then in the ajax call do: `model: urlHistory.getData()`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately your response is what I thought... But I hoped a better solution existed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but this helped me out a lot and hopefully it helps someone else.

When sending the data via ajax i just encoded and decoded it first

```
var object //this is your object with a prototype
var send_data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(object)); //this encodes and decodes 

$.ajax({
     url: '/someurl',
     type: 'post',
     data: send_data
})
```